# iPhone magnetometer wacky next to a car

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9

I am building an application for iPhone 5s & 6 (iOS 9+) and utilizing the Magnetometer to read the magneticHeading to determine the angle that the wheel is facing (the iPhone is flat). The rotation is working correctly and I get an accurate reading when testing on a table top. However, when I approach the car wheel the Magnetometer reading is wacky and the magnetic flux is changing as I approach the car wheel.

I was using the CLLocationManager's trueHeading/magneticHeading to determine the change in angles when the wheel is turned. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any help is appreciated ...